# Tracking down spam email source account in cPanel WHM

Tags: email, spam

Given a spam email header sent from a cPanel WHM server, is there a way to track down under which cPanel account it was sent from?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If it was sent through a mail client relaying through your mail server, you might be able to piece together who it was by looking at whatever authentication and transaction logs you have set up for your smtp service.

If it is an email sent by a spam bot dropped by an exploit in one of an account's web applications... that's not so easy.

(But if an account has ZenCart installed, check that first.)